# Building a tflite model for multi class classification

Tags: android, tensorflow-lite

I have read multiple codelabs in which Google classifies images belonging to one class. What if I need to use 2 or more classes. For example, if I want to classify whether an image contains a fruit or a vegetable, and then classify which type of fruit or vegetable it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily train a Convolutional Neural Network ( CNN ) using TensorFlow ( specifically using Keras ). There are tons of examples on the internet. See [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multi-class-classification-tutorial-keras-deep-learning-library/) and [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-simple-cnn-multi-image-classifier-31c463324fa).

Next, we convert the Keras saved model ( `.h5` file ) to a `.tflite` file using `tf.lite.TFLiteConverter`,

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file("keras_model.h5")
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api).

Now, in Android, we take a `Bitmap` image and convert it to a `float[][][][]`,

```
private float[][][][] convertImageToFloatArray ( Bitmap image ) {
   float[][][][] imageArray = new   float[1][modelInputDim][modelInputDim][1] ;
   for ( int x = 0 ; x < modelInputDim ; x ++ ) {
       for ( int y = 0 ; y < modelInputDim ; y ++ ) {
           float R = ( float )Color.red( image.getPixel( x , y ) );
           float G = ( float )Color.green( image.getPixel( x , y ) );
           float B = ( float )Color.blue( image.getPixel( x , y ) );
           double grayscalePixel = (( 0.3 * R ) + ( 0.59 * G ) + ( 0.11 * B )) / 255;
           imageArray[0][x][y][0] = (float)grayscalePixel ;
       }
   }
   return imageArray ;
}
```

Where `modelInputDim` is the model's input size for the image. The above snippet converts the RGB image to a grayscale image.

Now, we perform the final inference,

```
private int modelInputDim = 28 ;
private int outputDim = 3 ;

private float[] performInference(Bitmap frame , RectF cropImageRectF ) {
   Bitmap croppedBitmap = getCroppedBitmap( frame , cropImageRectF ) ;
   Bitmap croppedFrame = resizeBitmap( croppedBitmap );
   float[][][][] imageArray = convertImageToFloatArray( croppedFrame ) ;
   float[][] outputArray = new float[1][outputDim] ;
   interpreter.run( imageArray , outputArray ) ;
   return outputArray[0] ;
}
```

I have prepared a collection of Android apps which utilize TFLite models in Android. See [here](https://gist.github.com/shubham0204/629d9e8570ef2de733bb70808a3aff0d).

Comment: Where would I add the code which converts bitmap to float in something like tflite?